# Creating a JSON Array in Python using contents from a file

Tags: python

Well, I have a list of numbers inside of a file called "codes.txt", and I'm trying to sort them into an array like this:

```
{
  codes: [
    "430490",
    "348327",
    "923489"
  ]
}
```

Or just simply ["430490", "348327", "923489"]. How would I do this? I'm not trying to output this into a file, but create a variable that contains that JSON array.
I have this so far:

```
codefile = open('codes.txt', 'r')
codelist = logfile.readlines()
codefile.close()
for line in codelist:
  # ?
```

Comment: Please tell a bit more about how the `codes.txt` looks and how the data is present in it

Comment: We need to see the input lines. Also, you don’t create a JSON array in Python (or even JavaScript). In Python you create a dict, like you showed, and when you’re ready to save it disk, or share it, you give that dict a JSON _serializer_ which creates the JSON (and can also save it to disk).

Comment: What you've described isn't valid JSON. Are you sure you're working with JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you pretty much have it correct already:

```py
codefile = open('codes.txt', 'r')
codelist = codefile.readlines()
codefile.close()
data = {
    'codes': [code.strip() for code in codelist]
}

# This is a dict, if you need real json:

import json
data_json = json.dumps(data)
```

Edit: the code was wrong, it has been corrected and tried with the following content for `codes.txt`

```
430490
348327
923489
```

Comment: You seem to be pretty sure that this code will work. What contents of `'code.txt'` did you try this with and what does value does `data_json` have?

Comment: you're right, it was incorrect, my bad. I fixed it and provided the example used for `codes.txt`

Comment: I receive this error whenever I try it: `'TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict'`

Comment: Before my edit the last line was executing `json.loads`, which is the opposite operation (it loads a json string as a dict). This leads to the error you just reported

Comment: Oh wait, I didn't realise you changed loads to dumps, nevermind. It worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough:

```py
with open('codes.txt', 'r') as codefile:
    data = {
        'codes': list(codefile)
    }
```